# Alternate methods to achieve the effect of marquee tag

Tags: asp.net, html, marquee

Currently I am using `HTML5` and I am using the `marquee` tag to move the pictures inside my webpage. Here is my code:

```
<table style="height: 50px; width: 100%">
    <marquee  loop="infinite" scrollamount="5"  BEHAVIOR="ALTERNATE">
        <asp:image style="height: 300px; width: 500px" ID="Image1" ImageUrl="~/woman/a1.jpg" runat="server"></asp:image>
        <asp:image style="height: 300px; width: 500px" ID="Image2" ImageUrl="~/woman/a2.jpg" runat="server"></asp:image>
        <asp:image style="height: 300px; width: 500px" ID="Image3" Imageurl="~/woman/a3.jpg" runat="server"></asp:image>
        <asp:image style="height: 300px; width: 500px" ID="Image4" ImageUrl="~/woman/a4.jpg" runat="server"></asp:image>
        <asp:image style="height: 300px; width: 400px" ID="Image5" ImageUrl="~/woman/a5.jpg" runat="server"></asp:image>
        <asp:image style="height: 300px; width: 400px" ID="Image6" ImageUrl="~/woman/a6.jpg" runat="server"></asp:image>
        <asp:image style="height: 300px; width: 400px" ID="Image7" ImageUrl="~/woman/a7.jpg" runat="server"></asp:image>
        <asp:image style="height: 300px; width: 400px" ID="Image8" ImageUrl="~/woman/a8.jpg" runat="server"></asp:image>
    </marquee>
</table>
```

But I found that `HTML5` does not support `marquee` tag anymore. Is there any alternate methods to achieve the same effect?

Comment: somebody please answer..i could not able to find proper answer for this in google also.

Comment: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css3-animation-advanced-marquee/ see here http://plnkr.co/edit/kKdCjK4seDD2p8djpxGH?p=preview